# ImportError: .so: undefined symbol: Py_InitModule4

Tags: python, c, module

I am attempting to write a C extension module for python and am running into the error in the title. The module works under Python 2.7.6, but it produces the error when I try and run it under Python 3.4.0.

I run `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` to compile the code. This is what my `setup.py` looks like:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

setup(
    ext_modules=[Extension("_file", ["_file.c", "file.c"])],
)
```

I run the Python3 interpreter and type `import _file` and this is what happens:

```
>>>import _file
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /home/name/python/file/_file.so: undefined symbol: Py_InitModule4
```

As I said above, doing the same thing in Python 2.7.6 works perfectly fine. What am I messing up?

Comment: Did you build it separately under Python 3?

Comment: *facepalm* that was it! Make your comment an answer and I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Python 3.x library doesn't have all the same symbols as the Python 2.x library. Make sure you rebuild your module against 3.x before using it.